# Why do a lot of window managers not support object orientation?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, window-managers

**Note:** I did a brief search that turned up with few results, the only really relevant result being [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334966/win32-application-arent-so-object-oriented-and-why-there-are-so-many-pointers), so I don't think this has been fully asked before.

I've been looking into OS development a lot lately, and I've found that most, if not all, don't have fully Object Oriented window-application interfaces, Windows included. This is, of course, with the notable exception of bytecode interpreted languages such as C# (or CLI in general) and Java. (To clarify, I mean that they tend to create a window through a function, rather than through the creation of a class).

I can understand the smaller managers made for simplicity, such as [tinywm](http://incise.org/tinywm.html), but even larger window managers like [MetaCity](https://github.com/ccg/metacity/), [Fluxbox](http://fluxbox.org/), and [Openbox](http://openbox.org/) tend to be still not come from objects, but rather functions -- despite some being written in C++ as opposed to pure C (at least, as far as I understand).

This may be a naive question, but why is it done this way?
I understand that it is important to implement a non-object-oriented ABI for languages that do not support object orientation, but why can't it *also* provide higher-level hooks for languages that *DO* support object orientation?

Would it not arguably be easier for the programmer in the end to have such hooks, because it would allow easier development of software? Given advances in hardware, would the performance loss not be minimal in comparison to the benefits of how much easier it'd be to develop?

This has just been something that's bugged me for a bit, and I'm hoping that someone will have an answer.

**PS**: If my understanding is fundamentally wrong somewhere, feel free to correct me.

Comment: Heh, Win32 API was written in pure C, and then Object Oriented Hooks were provided. Now those hooks based library is called "MFC" and if you ever have done MFC, you then, sir, know what a mistake it is to do that way.

Comment: I didn't realize MFC was considered object-oriented, because it contains so many macros and non-object functions

Comment: @Bitwize It's written in C++ and it exhibits objects, classes, and inheritance: all of [Peter Wegner's OO criteria](http://www-public.int-evry.fr/~gibson/Teaching/CSC7322/ReadingMaterial/Wegner87.pdf). Let's not have another 'what is OO' discussion, in the absence of a generally accepted definition.

Comment: "why can't it also provide higher-level hooks"? The amount of work and support necessary might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just windowing. There aren't operating systems that have object-oriented APIs in terms of methods called via objects as in `myObject->method()` or `myObject.method().` Most of the ones we're using now have windowing APIs designed in the early 1980s (Windows for example, The X Window System, etc). There are language and ABI issues to consider. The only exception I can think of is OS/2's language-independent OO thing called [System Object Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Object_Model).

Formally speaking there is no difference between `method(object, ...)` and `object.method(...)` or `object->method(...)`, just a syntactic difference.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be fundamentally wrong somewhere, but it's an awkward way to say that. :)

Window managers typically are object oriented, but they're not designed around classes and objects as you might find in C++. What you tend to have is something along the lines of:

```
struct Object {
  ...
};

void DoSomething(Object* obj, ...);
```

All of the functions provided by the window manager manipulate the internals of Object, whether that's a button, a window, or some other widget. Most of the time, the programmer is expected to treat those objects opaquely and let the API manage their contents. As a programmer, you're still operating with objects, and methods on those objects. It's just that much of the coupling is broken and it doesn't look like what people expect object oriented programming to look like because the objects are parameters to the functions instead of the functions being properties of the objects.

Comment: I thought structs weren't considered objects in the same way that class structures were because they couldn't contain methods? Maybe I'm just comparing window-generation/creation to that of Java too much, but I find creating applications from classes to be a lot more intuitive than having a series of functions/handles/macros to handle it.

Comment: In C++, the only difference between a `struct` and a `class` is that `struct` default visibility is `public` and `class` is `private`. In C structs, you don't get member functions. C++ member functions generally end up calling something for `myobj->DoSomething(...)` that would look like `MyObject::DoSomething(myobj, ...)`, with the class variables bound in the local scope. The actual data layout in memory for structs and classes is pretty much identical. There's no real reason to say that a thing of a struct type is not an object. It all just comes down to the calling syntax.